# laptop mode in Linux vs solid state drive (SSD)

Tags: ssd, battery-life, powersave, laptop-mode

I have a device running Ubuntu 10.04 with SSD drive and want to optimize its power consumption. As far as I understood laptop mode documentation, it is intended for conventional disk drives.

**Does it make sense to configure laptop mode on Linux laptop with SSD drive in order to save power ?**

Comment: @pnuts As I wrote above "I have a device running Ubuntu ...", industrial device, so we stick to 10.04 to avoid expensive testing etc.

Comment: @pnuts It makes sense to optimize power settings if the device is in 97% use cases battery powered. Another reason are our custom drivers, some of them do not work with 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is quite necessary, since the prices of SSD is still quite high. On linux, it is more power-saving than in other commercial operating system. Futhermore, SSDs can only save up a little power, there will not be a too significant difference with the improvement of power.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what is the relation between power saving and SSD price. Can you be more specific ?